# Unable to get Helm to work with ECR

Tags: docker, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, helm

I'm using Helm v3 with AWS ECR on a Kubernetes cluster that was creating using Kops. I have checked and the role kops assigned to the nodes does have ECR permissions. When I deploy my helm chart I just get `imagepullbackoff` when doing `kubectl get pods` in the correct namespace.

Below is some of my helm chart code, I hope this is everything that's needed to debug this issue. BTW I have looked around on SO and google, both come up short on ECR with Helm and nothing for Helm 3 - was released recently.

Inside my `values.yaml`

```
image:
  repository: <number>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apigw
  # tag: latest
  tag: ef86dfe0b703
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Note that the tag there is a git commit ID and spinnaker will change that on each deployment so here being static is just to test.

I was following this guide and as a result changed some things that might have effected it.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/deployment-pipeline-spinnaker-kubernetes/

Main one I think that makes a difference is

```
 imagePullPolicy: "{{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}:{{ .Values.image.tag}}"
```

to

```
imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
```

However... If I change it back I get this error when trying to apply the helm chart

```
Error: Deployment.apps "apigw" is invalid: spec.template.spec.containers[0].imagePullPolicy: Unsupported value: "IfNotPresent:ef86dfe0b703": supported values: "Always", "IfNotPresent", "Never"
```

Comment: Did you add a secret to k8s in order to pull the image?

Comment: @030 No? I added nothing to K8's for the images? I have the ECR role assigned to my nodes which should be good enough. What kind of secret are you thinking of?

Comment: I meant `imagePullSecrets`, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding the image tag to the pull policy? you dont need it there, just leave it like this: `imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message it seems that the yaml is invalid:

```
Unsupported value: "IfNotPresent:ef86dfe0b703": supported values: 
"Always", "IfNotPresent", "Never"
```

It seems that `IfNotPresent` contains some tag and that is unsupported.